# Regular expression replace, maintaing original capitalization

Tags: regex, replace, capitalization

Using regular expressions, I would like to find and replace the word "foo" with the word "bar", but I want to do it in a way that preserves any capitalization that the word "foo" had before. So this text...

`Foo the foo, and FOO too`

would get changed to...

`Bar the bar, and BAR too`

Is there an easy way to do this with regular expressions?

Comment: Regex will only match, you have to post process each letter after a match. Traditionally its done with a callback function. What language?

Comment: No language exactly. I'm just refactoring some code using my text editor, so I was hoping I'd be able to do it with plain old RegEx, but it sounds like I probably can't. Oh well.

Comment: What text editor then? By the way some editors (such as Komodo Edit) have a search and replace that can preserve case exactly as you are requesting?